# Is there an lldb equivalent of gdb's 'bt full'?

Tags: lldb

I'm trying to show the variables in all stack frames, but haven't found a good way to do this in one shot like I can with `bt full`. The 'frame variable' only shows the variables in the current frame and there didn't seem to be any equivalent in the [LLDB mapping guide](http://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html).

Comment: Could someone give a little more insight into why this was considered "opinion-based"?

Comment: yeah I don't get that either.  It's a reasonable question.  As one of the authors of the gdb/lldb command map page, I hadn't heard of the "bt full" command before so it's not surprising it wasn't listed.

Comment: I placed a vote to reopen, I also don't see why this was closed.

Answer (score 3):

`bt all` is the short alias, `thread backtrace all` is the full command.

In the olden days, in gdb you needed to do `thread apply all backtrace` iirc, or `t a a bt` for short. They must have added `bt full` since then.  I'm not sure if I'm a fan of `bt full`, honestly.  Is it asking for a complete backtrace of a single thread?  Or a complete backtrace of all threads?  My first impression is that this would only give you a complete backtrace of one thread.

Anyway, not a big fan of gdb's `bt full` naming, not sure I'd want to add it as a recognized command in lldb, I think lldb's `bt all` shortcut is a good choice.